# Check Remote Server Load in node js

Tags: node.js, microservices

How to check the load of remote IPs/Server in node js or in any other framework . Basically I have a list of ips / instances. I want to select one IP which is having least cpu load for my program . How can I achieve this in node js(preference) or any other language/framework?

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js you can actually check CPU usage with it's [OS](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/os.html) module:

```
var os = require('os');
console.log(os.cpus());
console.log(os.totalmem());
console.log(os.freemem())
```

You can also use [os-utility](https://github.com/oscmejia/os-utils) module from Github:

```
var os = require('os-utils');

os.cpuUsage((usage) => {
    console.log( 'CPU Usage:' + usage); //it will be in %
});
```

You can create a function on every instance using above modules that can help you to return the CPU usage for every instance. Based on the usage you can run your program on intended Server/IP.